# git only add non-whitespace changes

Tags: git

I am trying to provide and commit only relevant changes.

In my `.gitconfig` I dropped `core.autocrlf = input` line to skip line ending conversion.

Now I don't know why but my line endings are still converting

Already checked similar solution given but nothing works.
I want to only commit non-whitespace changes.

I tried

```
git add myfile

git diff HEAD
--- /dev/null
+++ b/profiles/minimal/minimal.info
@@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
...content of file here (practically all is changed)
```

Now remove white space

```
git diff HEAD -w | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

and I get an error

```
error: myfile: already exists in index
```

Answer (score 2):

You are simply trying to add file which is **already was** added to the index.
You can't add it more than once. Looks like you have already executed this command or manually added the file using `git add`

---

What does the command does  (so others can learn):

```
git diff HEAD -w | git apply --cached --ignore-whitespace
```

Which does the following:

```
# Generate the diff between HEAD to index
git diff HEAD -w

# apply the patch to the index
```

> `git-apply`
>
> Apply a patch to files and/or to the index